# inserting selected row mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to use the row that I have selected and echoed to insert to a table again.
So what I want is row `to_user`. how should I define `$to_user` to get `to_user` row?

```
$to_user = $row['to_user']; //this gives me undefined variable error

$stmt = $mydb->prepare("insert into `messages`(`to_user`) values(?)");
echo $mydb->error;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $to_user);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
 $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['to_user'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row['to_user'];

$stmt = $mydb->prepare("insert into `messages`(`to_user`) values(?)");
echo $mydb->error;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $row['tu_user']);
$stmt->execute();
//get the last inserted id and store it in a var
$lastInserted = $mydb->lastInsertId();

        $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where id = ? ");
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $lastInserted);
         $stmt->execute();
             $result = $stmt->get_result();
//for testing
        //print_r($result);
       // echo $result;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['to_user'];}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already defined id. I am getting the id from another page.

Comment: try printing out `echo $row['to_user'];` and commeting out the pdo to see what really is in there?

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't make it clear, I need the `$row['to_user']` value which I am displaying on the select statements

Comment: `undefined variable row` is what I get still.

Comment: that's because it is.. it must be something silly like a misspell, track down everything that has to do with `$row,` and `$row[]` getting the `to_user` if you really cant find anything we can try the chat